# PHP - Adding string value to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, associative-array

This seem so simple, and yet I can't find a solution anywhere.

What I want to do is add the *contents* (r-value) of a variable to an associative array instead of a *reference* to the variable.

For example, I want this:

```
$myStr1 = "sometext";
$myStr2 = "someothertext";

$myArray = array(
    "key1"=>$myStr1,
    "key2"=>$myStr2
);

echo($myArray["key1"]);
```

To produce this:

```
"sometext"
```

Instead of this:

```
"1"        // why??
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The above works;  my bad.  Here's the *real* problem - my `$myStr1` variable isn't just assiged a string literal like in the above; it's created using the following syntax:

```
$myStr1 = "sometext" + anObject->intProperty + "moretext";
```

Basically I use the `+` to concatenate various types into a string.  Maybe `+` isn't doing what I think it's doing?

**EDIT:**

It was definitely the `+` operator.  I casted all non-strings to strings and used `.` to concatenate instead.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ywwma --- your code works as expected

Comment: Crap.  Well I guess I have some investigative work to do.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I'm using 5.4.3.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.4.4 and it works fine, so it's probably not the version. Does a simple, separate test file work?

Comment: I figured it out.  The problem wasn't anything to do with the array; rather, I was building a string using the `+` operator, thinking it was the same as the `.` operator.  Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Ah. Glad you have solved it. I thought it would be something like that. :-)

Comment: For the record the + operator in PHP only performs additions, and if you use it with strings it will just try to cast the strings to values (1) and add them. (just in case it was still unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it correct the first time.  [Try this:](http://ideone.com/V3BQN)

```
$myStr1 = "sometext";
$myStr2 = "someothertext";

$myArray = array(
    "key1"=>$myStr1,
    "key2"=>$myStr2
);

unset($myStr1);

echo($myArray["key1"]);
```

Even though we `unset()` the `$myStr1` variable, it still echoed `sometext`.

It should be noted that while it is possible to set `$myStr1` [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php), it's not the default.

Comment: Your answer is the same as the other one, plus the comment.

Comment: `&"sometext";` - it's not valid php. Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff in other words, I provide an actual answer, instead of a comment in answer form?

Comment: @zerkms noted, thanks.  Momentary brain lapse.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code and its result is:

```
sometext
```

Comment: Even though this may be considered as an answer, I still personally think it would be more suitable to leave it as a comment